# Bootstrap affix overlaps footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm facing a problem with Bootstrap 3 Affix.

When I scroll down the page, the affix overlaps the footer.

I've already tried adding "data-offset-bottom" but it seems that the affix jumps to the top and, after that, it doesn't scroll anymore.

I put the code here: http://www.bootply.com/JyWv1zG0MW

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/aYLkVcI0GCDQeyobudxI?p=preview check this

Comment: i suggest following these steps from the doc http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix-usage

Comment: Thank you for your effort, yuyokk!!! 

IT WORKS!!! :D